# Does LINQ work with IEnumerable?

Tags: .net, linq, ienumerable

I have a class that implements `IEnumerable`, but doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`. I can't change this class, and I can't use another class instead of it. As I've understood from MSDN [LINQ can be used if class implements `IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx#linqoverview_topic3). I've tried using `instance.ToQueryable()`, but it still doesn't enable LINQ methods. I know for sure that this class can contain instances of only one type, so the class could implement `IEnumerable<T>`, but it just doesn't. So what can I do to query this class using LINQ expressions?

Comment: Without casting the IEnumerable, instead of the all the linq methods you'll only see 8 methods: AsQueryable, Cast<>, Equals, GetEnumerator, GetHashCode, GetType, OfType<>, ToString

Answer (score 157, accepted):

You can use `Cast<T>()` or `OfType<T>` to get a generic version of an IEnumerable that fully supports LINQ.

Eg.

```
IEnumerable objects = ...;
IEnumerable<string> strings = objects.Cast<string>();
```

Or if you don't know what type it contains you can always do:

```
IEnumerable<object> e = objects.Cast<object>();
```

If your non-generic `IEnumerable` contains objects of various types and you are only interested in eg. the strings you can do:

```
IEnumerable<string> strings = objects.OfType<string>();
```

Comment: Every day, I learn something new about LINQ. Every day, I love it more and more.

Answer (score 14):

Yes it can. You just need to use the `Cast<T>` function to get it converted to a typed `IEnumerable<T>`. For example:

```
IEnumerable e = ...;
IEnumerable<object> e2 = e.Cast<object>();
```

Now `e2` is an `IEnumerable<T>` and can work with all LINQ functions.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use LINQ's query comprehension syntax, which casts to the type of the range variable (`item` in this example) if a type is specified:

```
IEnumerable list = new ArrayList { "dog", "cat" };

IEnumerable<string> result =
  from string item in list
  select item;

foreach (string s in result)
{
    // InvalidCastException at runtime if element is not a string

    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

The effect is identical to @JaredPar's solution; see *7.16.2.2: Explicit Range Variable Types* in the C# language specification for details.