# Cannot using Linq function with Bing API sdk on Winforms

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, bing, bing-maps

I'm using big api sdk on a winform application ( Winform and no WPF ! ).

I'm able to add PushPin.
I would like to delete somes pushpin.

I saw some linq method but i'm not able to compile because the "First" is not found. :

```
var pushpin = MyMapUserControl.MyMap.Children.First(p => (p.GetType() == typeof(Pushpin) && ((Pushpin)p).Tag == "FindMeLater"));
MyMapUserControl.MyMap.Children.Remove(pushpin);
```

My error :

```
'System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection' doesn't contain a definition for 'First' and no extensions method 'First' for a first argument 'System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection' has been found.
```

I add the include :

```
using System.Linq;
```

Anyone could help me please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection` implements `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable<UIElement>`, so the Linq methods do not directly apply since they only work on `IEnumerable<T>` instances.

One way is to "extract" the `PushPin`s as an `IEnumerable<PushPin>` using `OfType`:

```
var pushpin = MyMapUserControl.MyMap
                              .Children
                              .OfType<Pushpin>()
                              .First(p => p.Tag == "FindMeLater");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried, but i don't know why, i have a "System.InvalidOperationException": sequence don't contain any elements. I don't know why because a add a PushPin with a tag "FindMeLater".

Answer (score 1):

Use [Enumerable.OfType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
var pushPin = MyMapUserControl
                 .MyMap
                 .Children
                 .OfType<PushPin>()
                 .FirstOrDefault(p=> p.Tag == "FindMeLater");
if(pushPin != null)
   MyMapUserControl.MyMap.Children.Remove(pushpin);
```

`System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<T>`, thus LINQ will not be available. You may see this question [Does LINQ work with IEnumerable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757365/does-linq-work-with-ienumerable)

Comment: @Cory, the code in question shouldn't work, as `UIElementCollection` implements `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Got it; I wasn't aware that `OfType<T>` actually returned an `IEnumerable<T>`.