# convert foreach loop to linq

Tags: c#, linq, unity-game-engine, foreach

1. ***The Problem***

I want to convert a foreach loop to a linq statement.

2. ***The Details***

I have the following unity class (from metadata, removed most of the functions)

```
public class Transform : Component, IEnumerable
{
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator();
}
```

I have a local variable of this class (inherited) in my own class, which is

```
Transform transform;
```

On this I can do

```
List<Transform> children = new List<Transform>();
foreach (Transform t in transform)
    children.Add(t);
```

How can I do the same in a Linq expression?

Comment: Avoid `var` if you want us to understand your question.

Comment: Does `children = transform.Cast<Transform>().ToList();` work for you?

Comment: I will edit, though the type is directly on the right side.

Comment: I think it reads better with the `var`.

Comment: `Transform` is a class that contains `Transforms`? Or did you mean `children.Add(t.gameObject);` under point #2, instead of `children.Add(t);`?

Comment: @Enigmativity Normally, you're right. But to Tim's point, we don't have Intellisense or the other code to look at and tell us what those variables are. So if the assignments and variable names are not clear as to what types they are, it does obfuscate the code and make it harder for us to help.

Comment: @HimBromBeere He's referring to the OP

Comment: @Tim I now saw which var you mean and changed it, for other "var"s the type is right next to it.

Comment: Linq is nice to make code simple and readable, it is also recommended by Unity to avoid it when possible and use your own code. "– “Linq” — Examine the time lost to creating and discarding Linq queries; consider replacing hotspots with manually-optimized methods."

Comment: @AndreasReiff - would it have exhausted you to properly capitalise the question title?

Comment: and you should all listen to @fafase

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It must be an `IEnumerable<T>` in order to get access to the LINQ expressions.

One way to convert from `IEnumerable` to `IEnumerable<T>` is to use `OfType<T>` or `Cast<T>` extension methods (if you know the type).

e.g.

```
List<Transform> transforms = transform.Cast<Transform>().ToList();
```

See also [Does LINQ work with IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757365/does-linq-work-with-ienumerable)

Comment: Thanks! I just made my 10k rep. Whoo-hoo ! :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Enumerable.Cast`  if `Transform` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<Transform>`:

```
List<Transform> children = transform.Cast<Transform>().ToList();
```

otherwise it's simple as:

```
List<Transform> children = transform.ToList();
```

Comment: The question is not if `Transform` implements the interface, but if the `transform`-list does.

Comment: Did you edit? I think it was a little different before. Anyway, I will put solution gotten from your answer in original post for good formatting. Thanks!

Comment: @AndreasReiff: no, first version. Wait i've added after few seconds  the _" if Transform doesn't implement IEnumerable<Transform>"_