# Linq methods not available for a collection implementing IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, devexpress

I am trying to add an extension method for a [Bar](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraBars.Bar.class) class.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using DevExpress.XtraBars;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;

public static class BarExtensions
{
    public static BarItemLink GetBarItemLinkByTag(this Bar bar, object tag)
    {
        BarItemLink foundItemLink = null;
        bool a = bar.ItemLinks.Any(x => x.Item.Tag.Equals(tag));
        ...
    }
}
```

Item link is property of a [BarItemLinkCollection](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WPF/DevExpress.Xpf.Bars.BarItemLinkCollection.class) type. This class impelments `IEnumerable`.

But when I try to use any Linq method (e.g. *Any*), I got the error:

> 'DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItemLinkCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItemLinkCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I use DevExpress 15.1.7.

The question is what am I missing. Why I have no Linq methods available for the property?

Comment: Post the `using ...;` block of lines from the top of your file.

Comment: As @bommelding already mentioned, there must be something wrong with the usings. Your code compiles just fine on my machine.

Comment: @bommelding - done.

Comment: Still compiles on my machine. Which DevExpress version do you use?

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy The DevExpress version added - 15.1.7

Comment: I cannot find any documentation for this specific version but i assume that `IEnumerable` is returned and therefore you first have to use `Cast<T>()` or `OfType<T>` to get an `IEnumerable<T>` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7757411/3936440).

Comment: Does something like this work? `(bar.ItemLinks as IEnumerable<BarItemLink>).Any(x => x.Item.Tag.Equals(tag));`

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy  - Yeap, this worked. What I don't understand now is why my initial code compiles on your site. Does it mean that in your version of DevExpress IEnumerable<T> has been added to interfaces implemented by  BarItemLinkCollection?

Comment: Yep, i have DevExpress 18 and in this version `BarItemLinkCollection` implements `IEnumerable<T>`. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot find any documentation for the version 15.1.7 but I assume that `IEnumerable` is returned and therefore you first have to use `Cast<T>()` or `OfType<T>` to get an `IEnumerable<T>` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7757411/3936440).

So, I think you need to write

`bool a = bar.ItemLinks.Cast<BarItemLink>().Any(x => x.Item.Tag.Equals(tag))`