# Using LINQ on Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Lists collection

Tags: c#, linq, ms-word, office-interop

Using [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/), I am trying to iterate through the list objects in [Lists collection of Microsoft WORD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.lists?view=word-pia). But I'm getting the following error on the `Where` clause in the third line of my button click event below:

**ERROR**

> > List does not contain a definition for 'Where' and no accessible extension method 'Where' accepting a first argument of type 'List' could be found.

**CODE**

```
using System;
using MS_WORD = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.Linq;
....
private void BtnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Application application = new Application();
  Document document = application.Documents.Open("C:\\word.doc");

  MS_WORD.Lists oLsts = document.Lists.Where(n => n..Range.ListFormat.ListType == Word.WdListType.wdListSimpleNumbering);

  application.Quit();
}
```

**References**:

1. [ListFormat.ListType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.listformat.listtype)
2. [WdListType Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdlisttype?view=word-pia)

Comment: It only implements `IEnumerable`. You could use `document.Lists.Cast<MS_WORD.List>().Where(...)` to do the filtering but then you'll need to figure out how to convert `IEnumerable<MS_WORD.List>` to `MS_WORD.Lists` (assuming you need that at all).

Comment: @madreflection Your suggestion almost worked, now it gives the error `Lists does not contain a definition for 'Range' and  and no accessible extension method 'Range' accepting a first argument of type 'Lists' could be found`

Comment: You did `.Cast<MS_WORD.Lists>()` (with 's'). You want `.Cast<MS_WORD.List>()` (without 's').

Comment: @madreflection I had first tried without 's' and had gotten the error: `cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Ienumerable<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.List>' to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Lists'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast)`

Comment: That's why I initially said *"you'll need to figure out how to convert `IEnumerable<MS_WORD.List>` to `MS_WORD.Lists` (assuming you need that at all)."* Thing is, you probably can't and you don't really need to.

Comment: Instead, change the declaration to `List<MS_WORD.List> oLst = ...` and call `.ToList()` after the `Where`. You can iterate through that.

Comment: @madreflection I guess you mean: `List<MS_Word.List> oLsts = oDoc.Lists.Cast<MS_Word.List>().Where(........).ToList()`. And this code works (thank you). And if I use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7757411/1232087) suggested by `@mjwills`, I can also use `IEnumerable<MS_Word.List> oLsts = oDoc.Lists.Cast<MS_Word.List>().Where(.....)` without using `.ToList()` at the end of `Where` clause.

Comment: @mjwills Thank you. Your suggested [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7757411/1232087) helped me resolved the issue as follows: `IEnumerable<MS_Word.List> oLsts = oDoc.Lists.Cast<MS_Word.List>().Where(...);` Please also see my above comment.

Comment: Yep, you got my meaning. I'm glad that worked (you're welcome). I was being pedantic on the "list" aspect of it (although I did say *"you don't really need to [convert to a list]"*). You can always count on mjwills for thoughtful and helpful suggestions. Thanks mjwills!